# Formatting currency with java8 and java 11

Tags: java, android

I have an issue where the format returned from the exact same methods are different in different java versions.

```
  Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("CAD");
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  formatter.setCurrency(currency);
  formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
  System.out.println(" " + formatter.format(10.00)) ;
```

It returns `CA$10.00` in Java 11 but in Java 8 it's `CAD10.00`.

Is there any way I can get the prefix to always be CAD across Java versions? I know that `currency.getCurrencyCode()` returns CAD consistently across the versions. But I can't seem to find an overloaded method that let's me configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me. Looking through the source code, it appears that the `CA$` is the *currency symbol*. Seems like it was changed from `CAD` (in Java 8) to `CA$` (in later versions). The following line of code actually returns a `DecimalFormat` instance.

```java
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

You can explicitly set the currency symbol to `CAD`.

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Currency;

public class SchTasks {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("CAD");
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        formatter.setCurrency(currency);
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        dfs.setCurrencySymbol("CAD");
        ((DecimalFormat) formatter).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        System.out.println(" " + formatter.format(10.00)) ;
    }
}
```

You can run the above code from this *JDoodle*

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/s67